# folderbrowserdialog access to path is invalid

Tags: c#, wpf, windows-forms-designer, access-denied, folderbrowserdialog

Everytime i run the program it has an error that says access to the path is denied. i already check the folder allowed all users, unchecked the read only and still it wont work

```
private void button2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    try
    {
        FolderBrowserDialog fbd = new FolderBrowserDialog();
        DialogResult result = fbd.ShowDialog();
        string[] files = Directory.GetFiles(fbd.SelectedPath);
        textBox2.Text = fbd.SelectedPath;
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
          MessageBox.Show(ex.Message, "Error", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Error);

    }
}
```

Comment: At which line exception occurs?

Comment: You don't appear to be doing anything with the `DialogResult`. If you hit cancel, `SelectedPath` is going to be empty.

Answer (score 0):

Add a check on result.

```
DialogResult result = fbd.ShowDialog();
if (result == DialogResult.OK)
{
    string[] files = Directory.GetFiles(fbd.SelectedPath);
    textBox2.Text = fbd.SelectedPath;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Check this man..

```
private void button2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    try
    {
        FolderBrowserDialog fbd = new FolderBrowserDialog();
        DialogResult result = fbd.ShowDialog();
        textBox2.Text = (result == DialogResult.OK) ? fbd.SelectedPath : string.Empty;
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        MessageBox.Show(ex.Message, "Error", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Error);
    }
}
```